# Serialization for memcached

Tags: c#, serialization, caching, memcached

I have this huge domain object(say parent) which contains other domain objects. It takes a lot of time to "create" this parent object by querying a DB (OK we are optimizing the DB). So we decided to cache it using memcached (with [northscale](http://www.northscale.com/) to be specific)

So I have gone through my code and marked all the classes (I think) as `[Serializable]`, but when I add it to the cache, I see a Serialization Exception getting thrown in my VS.net output window.

```
var cache = new NorthScaleClient("MyBucket");
cache.Store(StoreMode.Set, key, value);
```

This is the exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

SO my guess is, I have not marked all classes as `[Serializable]`. I am not using any third party libraries and can mark any class as `[Serializable]`, but how do I find out which class is failing when the cache is trying to serialize the object ?

Edit1: casperOne comments make me think. I was able to cache these domain object with Microsoft Cache Application Block without marking them `[Serializable]`, but not with NorthScale memcached. It makes me think that there might be something to do with their implementation, but just out of curiosity, am still interested in finding where it fails when trying to add the object to memcached

Comment: @Ram: Do you have more information on what the requirements of northscale are?  It's more than likely an issue with them, and not necessarily with the framework, so more information on their requirements would help greatly.

Comment: @casperOne: We did a Proof of concept with "caching" strings, and it works. When trying to cache the domain object, thats when it fails. I am thinking its something from my side.Please also see Edit1 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved it. NorthScale was not throwing any error when the serialization failed. I serialized my domain object with Binary Serialization and was able to find out which classes were failing (since they were not marked as `[Serializable]`). Fixed it and it worked

Seeing the [results](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.1000000-times.2010-02-06.html) of protobuf-net I am thinking about switching my serializer too

Answer (score 2):

A common omission with `BinaryFormatter` is events; if you have objects subscribed that are *not* serializable, bad things happen. Plus you probably don't *mean* to serialize the subscribers. You can mark these as `[NonSerialized]` or `[field:NonSerialized]`.

If all else fails, give it the `byte[]` of your object (or if that fails, base64). That said, I would advise against `BinaryFormatter` here - it is [brittle](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html) and takes more bandwidth than it needs to. I've had some success using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) instead ([see here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/01/distributed-caching-with-protobuf-net.html), but a different implementation) ; which is [smaller, faster](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.1000000-times.2010-02-06.html), and version safe. I might be able to help shim this for you? Or you can use the `ISerializable` hook from protobuf-net.

Comment: nice one. I also see that Jon has something similar.Looks like yours is much easier to use, by just specifying the transcoder. Will give it a shot. And I guess I don't even have to mark the classes as `[Serializable]` as long as they are marked as `[DataContract]`

Comment: @Ram - note that with [DataContract] it will need explicit (and unique) Order on the `[DataMember]` - for example, `[DataMember(Order=1)]` ... `[DataMember(Order=2)]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu Debug -> Exceptions and expand Common Language Runtime Exceptions, then select the appropriate namespace for a `SerializationException` (System.Runtime.Serialization) and check the break when exception is thrown for the `SerializationException`.

This way you can check the details of the thrown exception.

Also note that a first chance exception does not absolutely mean that there is a problem with the application code.